# simple_html_dom find all elements that ONLY contain certain text

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I have:

```
 <span>something or other</span>
 <b>blarg</b>
 <b>blarg and stuff</b>
 <span>blarg</span>
 <em>wakka wakka</em>
 <em>wakka blarg</em>
 <em>blarg</em>
```

and I just want to get the elements that ONLY contain "blarg" and no other text, so:

```
 <b>blarg</b>
 <span>blarg</span>
 <em>blarg</em>
```

The important issue here is that I'm trying to check if blarg exists within one element alone on the page or not. I've had some general luck with regex but I'd rather do it with `simple_html_dom` so that I can look at child and sibling elements as well.

Does anyone know what is the simplest way to do this with `simple_html_dom`?

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: please refer this question its already answered .Hope it will help.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741644/php-simple-html-dom-parser-finding-specific-text

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it, is to parse every tag, and test if it contains 'blarg'...

Here's a working example:

```
$text = '<span>something or other</span>
 <b>blarg</b>
 <b>blarg and stuff</b>
 <span>blarg</span>
 <em>wakka wakka</em>
 <em>wakka blarg</em>
 <em>blarg</em>';

echo  "<div>Original Text: <xmp>$text</xmp></div>";

$html = str_get_html($text);

// Find all elements
$tags = $html->find('*');

foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
    // If text in tag contains 'blarg'
    if (strcmp(trim($tag->plaintext),'blarg') == 0) {
        echo  "<div> 'blarg' found in \$tags[$key]: <xmp>".$tag->outertext."</xmp></div>";
    }
}
```

I don't know what you want to do with, but this may be a start :)

Comment: This looks like my best bet thus far, but I thought there would be something shorter and cleaner built into simple_html_dom. I thought that there would be a way to use find() alone without having to loop through all elements??

Comment: AFAIK, there's none... I just found plenty of questions with similar answers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465690/php-simple-html-dom-parser-find-string

Comment: I am trying your method, Enissay, but it's not finding 'blarg' even though I know that it's there (I have the HTML being output). Any reason you can think of for this? I've tried uppercase, lowercase, etc just to make sure, still not found.

Comment: @zoltar, this code is working for me... You can try it sparately and you'll see... Then if you integrate it to you code, I cannot say what's not working unless I have the whole code... Be sure error reporting is enabled by adding these `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', '1');`